# syslog-ng, Установка в интерактивном режиме

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

Провели установку наборов пакетов на стенде выявили конфликт программ.
Проблема не появляется, когда идет установка при активном пользователе, но у нас этот прием не применим, т.к. установка и настройка ОС и ПО проводятся под root, без взаимодействия.
Решением удалить, отключить или остановить linux-kernel-log-daemon, проблему не решит.

```
> [SYSLOG-NG] Installing Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета libdbi1:amd64.
> (Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 218111 файлов и
> каталогов.) Подготовка к распаковке libdbi1_0.9.0-4_amd64.deb …
> Распаковывается libdbi1:amd64 (0.9.0-4) … Выбор ранее не выбранного
> пакета libesmtp6. Подготовка к распаковке libesmtp6_1.0.6-4_amd64.deb
> … Распаковывается libesmtp6 (1.0.6-4) … Выбор ранее не выбранного
> пакета libevtlog0:amd64. Подготовка к распаковке
> libevtlog0_0.2.12-7_amd64.deb … Распаковывается libevtlog0:amd64
> (0.2.12-7) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета libhiredis0.13:amd64.
> Подготовка к распаковке libhiredis0.13_0.13.3-2_amd64.deb …
> Распаковывается libhiredis0.13:amd64 (0.13.3-2) … Выбор ранее не
> выбранного пакета libivykis0:amd64. Подготовка к распаковке
> libivykis0_0.36.2-1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается libivykis0:amd64
> (0.36.2-1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета libmongo-client0:amd64.
> Подготовка к распаковке libmongo-client0_0.1.8-2_amd64.deb …
> Распаковывается libmongo-client0:amd64 (0.1.8-2) … Выбор ранее не
> выбранного пакета libnet1:amd64. Подготовка к распаковке
> libnet1_1.1.6+dfsg-3_amd64.deb … Распаковывается libnet1:amd64
> (1.1.6+dfsg-3) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета syslog-ng.
> Подготовка к распаковке syslog-ng_3.5.6-2.1_all.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-core. dpkg: относительно syslog-ng-core_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb,
> содержащего syslog-ng-core: syslog-ng-core конфликтует с
> linux-kernel-log-daemon   rsyslog предоставляет
> linux-kernel-log-daemon и и существует и установлен.   dpkg: ошибка
> при обработке архива syslog-ng-core_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb (--install):
> конфликт пакетов — syslog-ng-core не будет установлен Выбор ранее не
> выбранного пакета syslog-ng-mod-amqp. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-amqp_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-amqp (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-mod-geoip. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-geoip_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-geoip (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-mod-json. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-json_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-json (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-mod-mongodb. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-mongodb_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-mongodb (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-mod-redis. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-redis_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-redis (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-mod-smtp. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-smtp_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-smtp (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-mod-sql. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-sql_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-sql (3.5.6-2.1) … Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета
> syslog-ng-mod-stomp. Подготовка к распаковке
> syslog-ng-mod-stomp_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb … Распаковывается
> syslog-ng-mod-stomp (3.5.6-2.1) … Настраивается пакет libdbi1:amd64
> (0.9.0-4) … Настраивается пакет libesmtp6 (1.0.6-4) … Настраивается
> пакет libevtlog0:amd64 (0.2.12-7) … Настраивается пакет
> libhiredis0.13:amd64 (0.13.3-2) … Настраивается пакет libivykis0:amd64
> (0.36.2-1) … Настраивается пакет libmongo-client0:amd64 (0.1.8-2) …
> Настраивается пакет libnet1:amd64 (1.1.6+dfsg-3) … dpkg: зависимости
> пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет syslog-ng: syslog-ng зависит от
> syslog-ng-core (>= 3.5.6), однако:   Пакет syslog-ng-core не
> установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета syslog-ng (--install):
> проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным dpkg: зависимости
> пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-amqp:
> syslog-ng-mod-amqp зависит от syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:  
> Пакет syslog-ng-core не установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке
> пакета syslog-ng-mod-amqp (--install): проблемы зависимостей —
> оставляем не настроенным dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют
> настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-geoip: syslog-ng-mod-geoip зависит от
> syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:   Пакет syslog-ng-core не
> установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета syslog-ng-mod-geoip
> (--install): проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным dpkg:
> зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-json:
> syslog-ng-mod-json зависит от syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:  
> Пакет syslog-ng-core не установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке
> пакета syslog-ng-mod-json (--install): проблемы зависимостей —
> оставляем не настроенным dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют
> настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-mongodb: syslog-ng-mod-mongodb зависит
> от syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:   Пакет syslog-ng-core не
> установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета syslog-ng-mod-mongodb
> (--install): проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным dpkg:
> зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-redis:
> syslog-ng-mod-redis зависит от syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:  
> Пакет syslog-ng-core не установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке
> пакета syslog-ng-mod-redis (--install): проблемы зависимостей —
> оставляем не настроенным dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют
> настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-smtp: syslog-ng-mod-smtp зависит от
> syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:   Пакет syslog-ng-core не
> установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета syslog-ng-mod-smtp
> (--install): проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным dpkg:
> зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-sql:
> syslog-ng-mod-sql зависит от syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:  
> Пакет syslog-ng-core не установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке
> пакета syslog-ng-mod-sql (--install): проблемы зависимостей —
> оставляем не настроенным dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют
> настроить пакет syslog-ng-mod-stomp: syslog-ng-mod-stomp зависит от
> syslog-ng-core (= 3.5.6-2.1), однако:   Пакет syslog-ng-core не
> установлен.   dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета syslog-ng-mod-stomp
> (--install): проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
> Обрабатываются триггеры для libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) … При обработке
> следующих пакетов произошли ошибки: syslog-ng-core_3.5.6-2.1_amd64.deb
> syslog-ng syslog-ng-mod-amqp syslog-ng-mod-geoip syslog-ng-mod-json
> syslog-ng-mod-mongodb syslog-ng-mod-redis syslog-ng-mod-smtp
> syslog-ng-mod-sql syslog-ng-mod-stomp [SYSLOG-NG] Configured
> [SYSLOG-NG] UFW setting UDP 514 Правило добавлено Правило добавлено
> (v6) [SYSLOG-NG] done
```

Comment: Ну а при рабочем варианте - установщик каки-то вопросы задавал и вы на них отвечали?

Comment: Да, задавал по ходу установки

Comment: `debconf-get-selections | grep syslog` они?

Comment: пакет debconf-utils не установлен

Comment: Ну так установи

Comment: Вывод debconf-get-selections | grep syslog  ничего не вернул